# Countif only returns 1

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA and trying to write a statement that counts how many times the word "Male" Appears in a column. I am using this code:

```
Sub countif()
Dim StudentType As String
StudentType = "Male"
Dim ForeignCount As Long

ForeignCount = 0
   If WorksheetFunction.countif(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D10"), "Male") Then
ForeignCount = ForeignCount + 1
MsgBox ForeignCount
End If
End Sub
```

Message box display 1, in the column there in 4 instances of the word Male.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To be sure, the sheet is named "Sheet1", and by "...appears in a column", you mean "...appears in the range `D2:D10`"?

Comment: `If WorksheetFunction.countif(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D10"), "Male") ` is returning `True` not the count.  so foreigncount is only 1 `0+1`

Comment: get rid of the IF and just do `ForeignCount = WorksheetFunction.countif(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D10"), "Male")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the worksheetfunction the wrong way, the function returns the countif for you , just put in a variable.

```
       ForeignCount   = 0
       ForeignCount  = WorksheetFunction.countif(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D10"), "Male") 
       MsgBox ForeignCount
```